# amCharts LabelBullet not visible in Dumbbell plot charts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to add a Label to a Dumbbell plot (openValueY / valueY) points.
I can change the CircleBullet to a Triangle but struggle when adding LabelBullet.
I'm using the Demo code from https://www.amcharts.com/demos/dumbbell-plot/.
[Shows the Chart where I want to add a text label at each circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9QvU.png)
I added the following to the very end of the JavaScript section to keep the test simple:

```
let labelBullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
labelBullet.label.text = "Test";
```

Bu not luck so far.
I also played with:

```
labelBullet.label.fill = am4core.color('#000'); 
chart.maskBullets = false;
```

But couldn't get it to work!

I also moved the code to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Cloud4every1/k9mh1eby/
Maybe someone else has solved a similar problem or know a workaround/different solution.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because dumbbell plot is made from column chart by setting width of columns to 1px. And labels automatically are hidden if they do not fit into a column. To disable this, you must set:

`labelBullet.label.hideOversized = false;
labelBullet.label.truncate = false;`